# Ubuntu 14.04: problems upgrading php to 5.6 using ppa:ondrej

Tags: 14.04, php, ppa

I've done the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.6
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
```

When I try to disable the old version of php5 with:

```
sudo phpdismod php5
```

I get the error:
WARNING: Module php5 ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/5.6/mods-available

Even if I move the ini file under this directory it gives me the same error.  I don't know what I'm missing??

In general, can someone explain to me how to get my instance to use the newly installed version, as I still seem to have both php directory trees on my instance.  php5/.. and php/5.6

Comment: i think your upgrade not complete , you can check this link is how to upgrade http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html

Comment: Thank you for the link!  I followed but when I run phpinfo() from a test file in my directory it still shows that I'm running version 5.5.9.  However, when I do php -v from terminal it says PHP 5.6.21-9+dontate.sury.org~trusty+1, so it seems like 5.6 is installed correctly.  Any ideas how to get my application to run the right version?

Comment: if terminal write 5.6 it should work with 5.6

Comment: restart if not working correctly check if the problem with code

Comment: It's not running 5.6 for some reason.  It's like I need to change something in the apache config file to get the application to use the new version, but I don't know how.

Comment: check this link may help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are mixing different PPAs and versions and commands in incompatible way, let's break it down:

1. `libapache2-mod-php5.6` is present in `ppa:ondrej/php` and this is really the PPA you want to be using
2. `phpdismod` is a command for disabling PHP extensions, and not to manage Apache2 modules, you need `a2dismod` for that
3. The PHP Apache2 module in `ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6` is named `libapache2-mod-php5`

So the correct would be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge php5-common # remove and purge old PHP 5.x packages
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.6
```

If you don't uninstall `php5-*` packages first, you need to disable the `php5` module and enable `php5.6` module:

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php5.6
```

And optionally add Apache2 repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

There's a [migrationg guide](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/wiki/PPA-migration-to-ppa:ondrej-php) available for PPA packages.

Comment: Make SURE to also install any additional php modules you were using (mysql), as this one comes only with the bare basics.

Comment: You may also require:
`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`
`sudo apt-get install php-curl php-dev php-gd php-json php-mcrypt php-mysql php-readline php-sqlite3`